# Exporting datatables on AngularJS is showing only table headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I am integrating [datatables with buttons](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withButtons) into my AngularJS application.

Everything looks fine (pagination, column sorting, export buttons), but when I try to print/copy/export a table, it only outputs the headers, even though the rest of the data is there.

The data is loaded from a $http call:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $rootScope.apiURL+'getAllClientProducts/'+session,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(response){
    if(response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null){
        $scope.products = Object.keys(response.Result).map(function (key) {return response.Result[key]});
    }
})
.error(function(data){
    alert('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
});
```

These are my table options:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
.withDOM('frtip')
.withPaginationType('full_numbers')
// Active Buttons extension
.withButtons([
    'copy',
    'print',
    'excel'
]);
```

And this is the HTML for my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-sort="Name">{{ 'NAME' | translate }}</th>
        <th st-sort="Description">{{ 'DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</th>
        <th st-sort="Barcode">{{ 'BAR_CODE' | translate }}</th>
        <th st-sort="InternalCode">{{ 'INTERNAL_CODE' | translate }}</th>
        <th st-sort="SaleUnitType">{{ 'SALE_UNIT_TYPE' | translate }}</th>
        <th st-sort="UnitMeasure">{{ 'MEASURE_UNIT' | translate }}</th>
        <th st-sort="Status">{{ 'STATUS' | translate }}</th>
        <th>{{ 'ACTIONS' | translate }}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
        <td>{{ product.Name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.Description }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.Barcode }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.InternalCode }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.SaleUnitType }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.UnitMeasure }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.Status }}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="edit(product.InvProductId)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> {{'EDIT' | translate}}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever fix this, i'm having this problem atm